# What happens to objects that are declared inside of a function that are used as a return value? Why don't they get de-allocated on the return?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, garbage-collection, allocation

Let's say you have this: (boilerplate code left out)

```
static Object foo()
{
  Object test = new Object();
  return test;
}

Object output = foo();
```

At least in C#, the program doesn't crash when you try to use output even though it's pointing to the same object declared in foo. Why didn't it immediately get de-allocated?
And if this is a bad way to handle Object return values, is there a better way to deal with it?

Comment: "Why didn't it immediately get de-allocated?" Because garbage collection, and we're passing references. Love in C# is never having to say you're done.

Comment: "Love in C# is never having to say you're done." - That's deep @JeroenMostert :D Ken: By assigning the reference to `output` there is a strong reference to the object created inside the function. That's why the GC won't collect it. Why would that be "a bad way to handle Object return values" ? How else would you return a reference type?

Comment: Turn it around, why *should* the program crash? Isn't it crystal clear what you want to do here? Would you like the program to crash because you didn't explicitly tell it to make a copy suitable for access outside the function? Would you like to know exactly what's on the stack and what's on the heap at every point? If you said "yes", you can have a wonderful career as a C programmer -- but you (mostly) don't need to carry that mental baggage around when programming C#.

Answer (score 2):

The `GC` will only collect (if it so chooses to) objects that have no reachable references. In your example:

```
static object foo()
{
    object test = new object();
    return test;
}

object output = foo();
```

The instance referenced by `test` is also referenced by `output` when `foo` returns. So even though `test` is no longer a *reachable* reference, `output` still is, therefore, the instance its "pointing" to is not a candidate for collection.

The following example is radically different:

```
static object foo()
{
    object test = new object();
    return test;
}

foo();
```

Here, the instance referenced by `test` *is* a valid candidate for collection once `foo` returns (or even before, but lets ignore those optimizations) because once `foo` returns, there are no reachable references to the object.

Note that I'm using *reachable* references. An object might have valid references referencing it but still be a candidate for collection if the object containing the reference is also a candidate for collection. The `GC` is smart enough about these kind of cycles:

```
class A { public B b; }
class B { public A a; }

void Foo()
{
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    a.B = b;
    b.A = a;
}

Foo(); //both a and b are elegible for collection once Foo exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference passing. Object is a Reference type, meaning every single change made on it (including allocation) will be kept on the block where this Object have been declared.

If you did some C/C++, References are somewhat automanaged pointers.

Return it is not bad practice, but one should be careful about it. When you return the reference and assign it later, you'll lose the previous version if you happened to allocate it already before. Again, if you did some C, it's like making your pointer point on a second allocated memory part, leaving the first one (in the previous exemple case).